# Is it possible to make a variable dedicated to a certain author Discord.js?

Tags: discord.js, setinterval

I'm making a store bot and I ran into some SetInterval errors.  I want to make it so each variable has the user's id so when I run a different command, it will know which interval to stop.  (If that makes sense).
Here is my code:

```js
if(message.content.startsWith(`!open`) {
    var cashier1[message.author.id] = function () {
        BalanceJSON[message.author.id].bal += 10
        Fs.writeFileSync(`./DB/balance.json`, JSON.stringify(BalanceJSON));
    }
    setInterval(cashier1[message.author.id], 5000);
}
```

All this code is in a `bot.on('message', message => { })`

I wanna be able to stop an certain player's interval with `clearInterval(cashier1[message.author.id])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `setInterval` [returns a unique id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#return_value) which can be used to clear the interval again ([See the example for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#example_2_alternating_two_colors)).

The solution to your problem is to store the unique id of the interval in some object or database and use that to clear the interval again. See the example code below:

```js
// Create an object to store the intervals.
const cashierIntervals = {};

// Inside your message handler.
// Some dummy if statement for demonstration purpose.
if (message.content === 'setInterval') {
  // Create the setInterval and store the unique id in the cashier intervals object.
  // You should probably add more checks to see if there is already an interval stored for this author id etc.
  cashierIntervals[message.author.id] = setInterval(() => {
    BalanceJSON[message.author.id].bal += 10;
    Fs.writeFileSync(`./DB/balance.json`, JSON.stringify(BalanceJSON));
  }, 5000);
} else if (message.content === 'clearInterval') {
  // Clear the interval based on the author id.
  // Again, probably add more checks to see if the author id has an interval stored etc.
  clearInterval(cashierIntervals[message.author.id]);

  // Delete the stored interval entry from the global intervals object.
  // Not necessary but it keeps the intervals object small.
  delete cashierIntervals[message.author.id];
}
```

Comment: I just tried that, but the number 10 was still being added to my balance.

Comment: Where did you define the `const cashierIntervals = {};`? It should be outside of the `bot.on('message', (message) => {})`

Comment: Oh I didn't put it outside but I just did and it fixed it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Create an object that takes an id as a key. Your value will be the function you want to interval

Your main file:

```js
const cashier1 = {
   // Template for your key:values
   '999999999': yourRepeatingFunction(),
}

// Lets say message.author.id returns '999999999'
// Doing setInterval(cashier1[message.author.id], 5000) Will call yourRepeatingFunction()
```

Comment: So inside `const cashier` is where the user ID would go?  Because I need to make it where it will store their User ID's as they run a command and not pre stored.

Comment: To create new mey values you would simply assign them as such. `cashier1[message.author.id] = value`, You will need to handle values which already exist